# How to do realtime location updates with firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement a feature in my `Flutter` app where I want to share the live location of a user with his friends(just like whatsapp). How can I do that with Flutter and Firestore?.
I tried to save the coordinates to firestore everytime a user's location is changed and listening that query stream in his friend's app. But, that would cause just tooooooo many reads and writes.

What is the best way i can implement it. I know I'm not sharing any code because i don't think that is necessary.

How can I push realtime location of a particular user to his friends using Flutter and Firestore?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this method:

1- Store the current location of the user in Firestore for the first time and store it in the phone cache.

2- In the background, check the user’s location whether or not he changed his location based on a timer, so that we consider it to be 5 minutes each time he compares the current location with the site that was stored in the cache.

3- **In case the location has changed**, you can connect to Firestore and store the new location, if it has not changed, do not connect to Firestore.

In this method, you can provide reading and writing based on a simple
condition.

Comment: Adel's answer is correct, I just want to suggest using the Realtime Database to hold your location data instead of Firestore because the RTDB doesn't charge for each read/write and could be substantially cheaper.